Is a quantum state lorentz covariant?
Quantum states are defined on a equal-time time slice. However, an equal-time slice is not an equal-time slice for another boosted frame. So in order for formulation of  quantum theory to be Lorentz covariant, we must have a highly non-trivial unitary transformation of the state. Note that this is a generalized notion of Lorentz covariance, where the unitary transformation isn't simply generated by the Lorentz group generator. Instead, it must be a superposition of unitary transformation generated by the Poincre group.

Have you heard of Bogolyubov transformations?

@JeanbaptisteRoux I've seen it in the context of qft in curved spacetime, but I don't see how that one is related to what I'm looking for. Can you provide any reference?

Anything related to the Unruh effect would be a good introduction to using these transformations in flat space.

@JeanbaptisteRoux Thank you. I'll review it and see how I can adapt it for my purpose.

@JeanbaptisteRoux Also, I'll appreciate it if you could tell me exactly what the transformation I'm looking for looks like

I think you are asking for something like $a^\mathrm{boosted}i = \sum{j}(u_{ij} a_j^\mathrm{rest}+v_{ij} a^{\dagger,\mathrm{rest}}_i)$, where $u$ and $v$ are the Bogolyubov coefficients.

@JeanbaptisteRouxJe Yes something like that if linear transformation will do the job. I mean this should be a textbook level result if it is trivial to solve. But I can't find it anywhere so probably it's really hard and deserves a short publication if it is worked out.
